# Can I view which cities are low on food or have no food without clicking each one?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm at a point where I have around 40 cities (I kept playing after winning just for fun) and the stats screen popped up for "Most Well Fed" and I noticed my number was extremely low. I have farmland up the wazoo, so I was wondering *which* cities weren't so well-fed so maybe I could work on getting those specific ones some food, or halt population growth there so they don't run out of food.

I can't seem to find any screen that will outline all my cities and how much food they have, but I don't really want to click through every single city to look at the stats. I know that when a city starts starving, the red citizen icon will start appearing to notify you of that, but I'd rather not wait until that point because that will affect happiness until that extra citizen dies off from the food shortage.

Is there any simple way to view the food (and possibly other) stats for each city all at once? Or perhaps some other way to find starving cities?

Comment: Notably, one of the few things on the crummy sort-of-overview I pointed out there, is population of each city, and also its current growth info. See the third image in the answer.

Comment: @Billy Didn't know that icon was a button. Actually, clicking the Economic Overview thing at the bottom of the list gives me *exactly* what I want. The list of cities also includes how much food each city still has left. :) Let me find a few that were at 0 and 1...

Comment: Glad to have helped!